# vim to interpret escape characters ("\n", "\t") as does echo

Tags: formatting

I need an option in vim to display a text file, say `text-file`, during the session as would

```
echo -e `cat text-file` | vim -
```

- vim is given `text-file`
- `text-file` includes text with escape sequences, such as:

  ```
  FIELD 1             TEXT\tOF\n\tFIELD 2\n
  FIELD 1             TEXT OF FIELD 2
  ```
- vim to interpret escape sequences, so that `text-file` in the
  example above would be displayed in vim as:

  ```
  FIELD 1             TEXT    OF
      FIELD 2

  FIELD 1             TEXT OF FIELD 2
  ```

Answer (score 2):

A workaround would be to invoke the command from within Vim, allowing you to display escaped characters:

```
:%!echo -e "$(cat)"
```

Here, `%` is a range equal to the entire file, and `cat` is used to pass the standard input to `echo -e`.

The problem is that you won't be able to determine which tabs or newlines were delimiters and which were not, thus loosing the ability to revert the file to its original state.

If you have to save the file, you will need to apply a method similar to what [garyjohn proposed](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/13587/12003), that is replacing with substitute (`:%s`) either delimiters themselves or those found in the data before and after editing.

Comment: thanks LEI. before I read more about Vim, considering the problem you mentioned: can Vim direct its display-text through a pipe, such as the mentioned `echo -e`... yet meanwhile: the editing/working copy that Vim processes would remain the original? this would be like the preview-window of the stack-exchange post user interface. the text would be passed through the pipe automatically after every command entered. editing would be done as ed-commands in the bottom line (because the cursor would be another problem here).

Comment: edit - replace parenthesis at end of comment (because ... here) with: (because the cursor would indicate the wrong location)

Comment: As I mentioned I think you can't reliably get back to the original state once `echo -e` transformed `\t` and `\n`, unless your data follows some consistent pattern (then the task might still be complex). You could edit your question to clarify your goal, I am not sure to get it. Also check out [`:redir`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/various.txt.html#%3Aredir) to control the output of Vim commands.

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to put this line in your `~/.vimrc` file,

```
set listchars+=tab:>-
```

and when you want to edit a data file, execute

```
:set list
```

This will display most special characters so that they can be easily recognized without affecting the layout of the file.

If you really want newlines to appear as `\n` and tabs to appear as `\t`, you could execute the following substitutions.

```
:%s/\n/\\n/g
:%s/\t/\\t/g
```

When you're done editing, you can convert them back to actual newlines and tabs with the following.

```
:%s/\\n/\r/g
:%s/\\t/\t/g
```

Note that Vim represents newlines as `\n` in patterns and as `\r` in replacement strings.

For more, see:

```
:help 'list'
:help 'listchars'
:help /\n
:help sub-replace-special
```

Comment: thanks, your answer gives a way to display a tab as >---... no? that's useful too, but I intended to ask the the reverse -- how to cause that the esape sequences "\n" and "\t" be displayed as space and tab, respectively. (maybe that wasn't clear: I need practice in editing)

Comment: I suppose I focused too much on your line beginning with "solution:" and didn't read the rest closely. In any case, I thought the Vim conceal feature might solve this. It can be used to make the string `\n` appear as a space, but the replacement character cannot be a control character, so it can't be used to make the string `\t` appear as a literal tab. So I guess I don't have the answer you were looking for.